# get first row as key (dictionary) and rest of the row (values) in list python?

Tags: python

I am trying to read a text file which contains a number of columns and dump the array into a dictionary. The first row would be a key of the dictionary, and the rest of the rows are list (values of the key), in which the header has : separation
Data is from a text file not from a csv

```
DateTime:  Column1: test result: bar date:
 1-2-2012    a replicate    postive   1-3-2012
```

Expected output:

```
{'DateTime':'1-2-2012','Column1':'a replicate','test result':'postive','bar date':'1-3-2012'}
```

Comment: Hi! Please show us what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: This is not a CSV - there are no commas.  Is it really **tab** delimited?  Having **space** in column headers and as delimiters will cause you no end of pain in parsing it.

Comment: this data is from a text file not from a csv

Answer (score 0):

if your data is **tab** delimited you can use this approach

1. get keys from first record
2. get values from matching position in second record

if it's really **csv** delimited then `split()` using comma

```
data = '''DateTime:\tColumn1:\ttest result:\tbar date:
1-2-2012\ta replicate\tpostive\t1-3-2012'''
{t:data.split("\n")[1].split("\t")[i] for i, t in enumerate(data.split("\n")[0].split("\t"))}
```